# how to get Id of row when pop up option click (got Id using global variable)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to get Id of row when pop up option click ?I generated the row dynamically when "add" button is press.on Row there is an icon ":" ,on click of icon it show pop up screen When I click "edit" or other option I want to show Id of row on which it it open .I am able to get event of edit .But not able to get id.
http://jsfiddle.net/4ajeB/5/

```
function createTestCase(testCaseName, iscreatedFromScript, jsonObject) {
    var id;
    if (typeof ($("#testCaseContainer li:last").attr('id')) == 'undefined') {
        id = "tc_1";
        var index = id.indexOf("_");
        var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length);
        count = parseInt(count);
        var conunter = count;
    } else {
        id = $("#testCaseContainer li:last").attr('id');
        var index = id.indexOf("_");
        var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length);
        count = parseInt(count);
        var conunter = count;
        id = id.substring(0, index) + "_" + parseInt(count + 1);
    }
    var html = '<div class="testcaselist_row">' + '<ul>' + '<li id="' + id + '" class="clickTestCaseRow"><a href="#" style="color: #ffffff!important;">' + id + '<i class="icon1 test_h"></i></a></li>' + '</ul></div>';
    $('#testCaseContainer').append(html).enhanceWithin();
}

$('.edit_h').click(function(){

 alert("edit"+$(this).id)   

})
```

I got the ID using global variable.Can it is possible to get ID without using variable ?

Comment: your fiddle seemed to work for me in the latest firefox

Comment: @Derek it work fine but I used global variable

Comment: @Superdrac can you please change my fiddle ? can it is possible to append on row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the ID to the `.edit_h` as data, and access it in the `click` event.

```
    ...
    $('.edit_h').data('originalId', id);
    $('#testCaseContainer').append(html).enhanceWithin();
}

$('.edit_h').click(function(){
    alert("edit ID:"+$(this).data('originalId'));
})
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ajeB/6/

Comment: your answer is correct can you example what is the use of data ?

Comment: can you please give me api link where data is explain